# Flex video/audio chat for a site

Tags: apache-flex, flash, video

Looking for a component which can be embedded inside my site (PHP, ASP.NET...whatever) and give a support for video chat.

I'm not a flex developer and would like to use a component. There are some/many video chats available, like flashcoms, red5chat...but all of those are heavy(monolit) components.

What I would like to have on my site is just a small video showing output from my camera (me) and another video showing the other party...but those videos should be split, not in the same flash component, but separate (two different EMBED tags on my page).

Are there any components available to do that (of course with support from appropriate media server)? Are there any good guides on how to develop such a component?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I don't know of a specific Flex component designed for that. I'm not sure I'd recommend trying to implement it as two separate SWFs either. If you're willing to consider a custom development job, feel free to contact me personally. http://www.flextras.com/?event=ContactForm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to program in flash, there is no stright direct components just waiting to be implemented, you can use flash CS3 instead of flex!! 
Which let you built an small video object to display the camera, publish it, and then capturing on another swf with an small video object but there you play a NetStream Object and add it to an Video Object and voila!!!